# How to store a file in the database with Grails

Tags: grails, file-upload

I need to store a file in the database using Grails. So, do you know how I can do that? Which data type should I use in the domain class (byte[] might be a solution)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Chapter on Uploading Files in the [Grails User Guide](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#uploadingFiles). It is also possible to use a java.sql.Blob as type for the binary content (which would be preferable when dealing with huge files).

Comment: this is now a dead link

Answer (score 5):

alternatively, store the file on disk, and store the path to it in the database. it is generally faster to access that file on disk than in a db. but of course, that really just depends on your needs in the app. But be aware of this alternative.

Comment: I am aware of this alternative since I have used both in PHP. I think that I will use the file system option, since it is easy to move the whole file repository in order to scale the application and/or the storage. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

You can force the domain object to use a specific type when updating or generating the database with column mappings:

```
byte[] orgFile

static mapping = {
   columns { 
    orgFile type:'blob'
   }
}
```

This has worked for me so far ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem. All I needed to do was to go to the database (Oracle) and change the column type from RAW to Blob. (Actually I had to remove the column and then to create a new one). 
I was never able to find out how to use a "java.sql.Blob" as suggested above. I found this [this (converting from bytes to Blob)](http://capitalcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2008/05/mapping-document-from-byte-to-blob-in.html), but it seemed a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used byte[] in a domain class for storing file, it was working fine until i moved my application from "HSQLDB" to "Oracle express".
On Oracle, byte[] was mapped to a raw object instead of blob... (not sure of what was exactly wrong) and I finally solve the problem by using a java.sql.blob