# How to split a large file into small chunks (in Grails) so as to insert into a db as a BLOB

Tags: grails, file-upload, blob, filesplitting

We are using Grails 2.0.1 I have a controller which reads a uploaded file from my GSP as inputstream , I want to split this file into chunks in the controller so as to be able to insert the file data in the form of BLOB type in my underlying DB.! please Help Is there any particulat function from java.sql.BLOB ?

Comment: Possible answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721358/how-to-store-a-file-in-the-database-with-grails

Comment: Thank you, @SagarV . but i am looking for splitting the file into chunks and then use an outputstrem to store that chunk.

Comment: Did you try to make `inputstream` from it, and use it for spliting?

Comment: Why do you have to split it? You are already using a binary LARGE object as datatype...