# Property xxx is type-mismatched

Tags: grails

I'm trying to build simple CRUD application using Grails. I'm absolutely new to this framework. My CRUD table has few properties, connected to a local database and it works so well except it can't load pictures in it. I get a error that it's type mismatched. How to solve it?

My controller class is below:

```
class Person 
{
    int id
    String name
    String address
    byte[] profilePic
}

static constraints 
{
    profilePic maxSize :204800
}

static mapping 
{
    table 'all_users'
    version false
    columns 
    {
        id column: 'id'
        name column: 'name'
        address column: 'address'
        profilePic column: 'profilepic'
    }
}
```

Comment: If you see errors in your console etc, please add them to the question (e.g. stacktraces, ...). "Does not work" makes it hard to guess, what goes wrong.  Also please make sure, that your code there is pasted properly.  Those static blocks outside of the class look absolutley wrong.

Comment: @cfrick i get a error Property image is type-mismatched when i try to load an image in "Choose file" field

Answer (score 0):

Domain Code

```
class Person 
{
    int id
    String name
    String address
    String profilePic
}

static mapping 
{
    table 'all_users'
    version false
    columns 
    {
        id column: 'id'
        name column: 'name'
        address column: 'address'
        profilePic column: 'profilepic'
    }
}
```

Controller Code

```
def save(){
        def person = new Person(params)
        person.save flush: true, failOnError: true
        redirect action: "show", id: person.id
        def downloadedfile= request.getFile('profilePic')
        String profilePic = "D:/Your Grails Applications/grails-app/assets/images/" + person.name + ".jpg"
        downloadedfile.transferTo(new File(profilePic))
    }
```

View Code

```
<input type="file" name="profilePic"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#uploadingFiles and [How to store a file in the database with Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721358/how-to-store-a-file-in-the-database-with-grails)